# How can I reject all request except GET request

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I am building .NET 5 WebAPI.

I need a filter or policy that rejects all verbs except GET even if the route and the verb do match.

Can I do this in Startup class?

Comment: May I ask why you have routes with verbs other than GET if you don't intend to allow them to be reached?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Because this project has a lot of developers involve and I don't have any other senior to review all the code that junior dev write. In testing and prod servers, this API won't allow doing anything but to get the data all traffic will be sniff and filter by the application firewall which inspects HTTP verb so this piece of code will help any junior dev avoid "it works in my PC" situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [MapWhen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.mapwhenextensions.mapwhen?view=aspnetcore-5.0) you can branch based on a predicate:

```
app.MapWhen(context => !context.Request.Method.Equals("GET", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase),
  (IApplicationBuilder builder) =>  
  {  
    builder.Run(async context =>  
    {  
      await Task.FromResult(context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status406NotAcceptable);  
    });  
  });
```